# Using Selenium in python with headless Chrome from a Docker container

Tags: python, selenium, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm creating a Dockerfile from an official base jupyter sci-py image (docs [here](http://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-scipy-notebook), Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/scipy-notebook/Dockerfile)).

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

USER root

# bash instead of dash to use source
RUN ln -snf /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

USER jovyan

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
 && pip install gspread \
 && pip install isort \
 && pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions \ 
 && pip install nbdime \
 && pip install pathlib \
 && pip install selenium \
 && nbdime extensions --enable

RUN jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

RUN jupyter nbextension enable autosavetime/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/edit \ 
 && jupyter nbextension enable code_prettify/isort \
 && jupyter nbextension enable scratchpad/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable splitcell/splitcell \
 && jupyter nbextension enable table_beautifier/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable code_prettify/2to3 \
 && jupyter nbextension enable init_cell/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable spellchecker/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable toggle_all_line_numbers/main \
 && jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main
```

I am running this container with

```
docker run -v my_dir:/home/jovyan/work -p 8888:8888 -a stdin -a stdout -i -t my_image /bin/bash
```

The directory I'm mounting contains the chromedriver executable.

When I open my Jupyter notebook and run the following code

```
import datetime
import os

import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_path = '/home/jovyan/work/data_analysis/notebooks/sandbox/miguel/tests/chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
# chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome   Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/jovyan/work/data_analysis/notebooks/sandbox/miguel/tests/chromedriver'
```

These may be helpful in tracing the error:

- (from Jupyter notebook) `!pwd` returns `/home/jovyan/work/data_analysis/notebooks/sandbox/miguel/tests`
- (from Jupyter notebook) `!ls` returns `chromedriver` among other files
- (from Jupyter notebook) `!google-chrome --version` returns `Google Chrome 68.0.3440.75`

I've googled the error but couldn't find an answer. Also, if there is a simpler/better way of achieving this (using Selenium with Chrome from a Docker container), I'd be happy to take another approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely doable using `jupyter/scipy-notebook` as a base image, however I used `debian:stable`.

I create my project file using `$ touch script.py` and use Selenium to instantiate a Chrome browser instance (and perform a test request to verify that Selenium is working properly):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://httpstat.us/200")

if "200 OK" in driver.page_source:
    print('Selenium successfully opened with Chrome (under the Xvfb display) and navigated to "https://httpstat.us/200", you\'re all set!')
```

Then, I create the invocation shell script using `$ touch run.sh`. I want to use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to create a X Windows server within this container for the Chrome browser instance:

```
# Below is the reason for "-nolisten tcp" (this is not documented within Xvfb manpages)
# https://superuser.com/questions/855019/make-xvfb-listen-only-on-local-ip
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp &
python3 test.py
```

Now, I'll create the following `Dockerfile`.

First, I'm going to install chromium, Xvfb, and Python:

```
FROM debian:stable 
LABEL maintainer "Sean Pianka"

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y wget curl unzip libgconf-2-4
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y chromium xvfb python3 python3-pip 
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
```

Then, I'll create my project's directory, install selenium (and/or my project's dependencies), and copy my project code into the image.

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip3 install selenium
## or install from dependencies.txt, comment above and uncomment below
#COPY requirements.txt .
#RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY test.py .
```

Lastly, I'll set `DISPLAY` to an open display port for Xvfb to use for the X Windows server it creates, copy the `run.sh` script into the image, and invoke the script using `/bin/bash`.

```
# Set display port and dbus env to avoid hanging
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
# Bash script to invoke xvfb, any preliminary commands, then invoke project
COPY run.sh .
CMD /bin/bash run.sh
```

This completes the `Dockerfile`, and now if you create a container using the image of this, you will see the following output from our `test.py` file:

> Selenium successfully opened with Chrome (under the Xvfb display) and navigated to "https://httpstat.us/200", you're all set!

If you would like pre-written Dockerfiles for any combination of Python 2/Python 3 and Chrome/Firefox, see [my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/seanpianka/docker-python-xvfb-selenium-chrome-firefox) which contains these different `Dockerfile` versions.